# Volley Error Response Null

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm first time using JSONVolley
I'm stuck in `Response.ErrorListener()`

```
error.getMessage() is always null don't know why
```

I'm getting data from `localhost` and using mobile. If i use emulator then its working fine.

Issue is when i get data from any other json example available on internet
It gets the data but when i use my `localhost`. It didn't get the data.

Here is my Volleycode:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/diygeeks/posts.json";    
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray heroArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject jresponse = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DiyPosts posts = new DiyPosts(jresponse.getString("status"),imgUrl);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jresponse.getString("status"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PostsList.add(posts);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                adapter = new PostsRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), PostsList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

JSON Structure of WordPress:

```
            [{"id":2107,"date":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","date_gmt":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","guid":{"rendered":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/?p=2107"},
        "modified":"2017-09-28T07:32:09","modified_gmt":"2017-09-28T07:32:09",
    "slug":"flute-test","status":"publish","type":"post","link":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/2017\/09\/28\/flute-test\/",
    "title":{"rendered":"Flute Test"},'
"content":{"rendered":"<figure id=\"attachment_2108\" style=\"width: 300px\" class=\"wp-caption alignnone\"><img class=\"size-medium wp-image-2108\" src=\"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-300x210.jpg\" alt=\"error\" width=\"300\" height=\"210\" srcset=\"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-300x210.jpg 300w, http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-768x538.jpg 768w, http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-1024x717.jpg 1024w, http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd-545x382.jpg 545w, http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/flute_player_ii_by_uitarifd.jpg 1068w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" \/><figcaption class=\"wp-caption-text\">Flute writing<\/figcaption><\/figure>\n","protected":false},"excerpt":
    {"rendered":"","protected":false},"author":1,"featured_media":0,"comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","sticky":false,"template":"","format":"image","meta":[],"categories":[50],"tags":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2107"}],
    "collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"}],"about":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"}],"author":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"}],"replies":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=2107"}],"version-history":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2107\/revisions"}],"wp:attachment":
    [{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=2107"}],"wp:term":[{"taxonomy":"category","embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=2107"},{"taxonomy":"post_tag","embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/diygeeks\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=2107"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}}
```

It's not complete JSON. because JSON of wordpress is too complex and lengthy

Comment: when you want to get the data from localhost then you need to connect your device to the same network

Comment: @ShubhamJain laptop and mobile both  connected to same network

Comment: Saad have you check this API on postman too.

Comment: @ShubhamJain nope. i didn't check API. basically my friend gave my wordpress built in API and i just copied the link of JSON and paste into my android. that link gives me json structure of wordpress site.

Comment: post your json here @MuhammadSaad

Comment: @NavneetKrishna done .

Comment: This is not the right way to integrate volley. you are missing the request type, it should be StringRequest instead and log on the response better.

Comment: @Ibrahim okay i'll explore more about right way. but would you tell me about null issue?

Comment: @MuhammadSaad **because this is not the right way to integrate volley**

Comment: @Ibrahim thank you :)

Comment: @Ibrahim i've updated my code. But still same issue